# Bus from Gorlitz (Germany) to Zgorzelec (Poland)

Tags: germany, buses, poland

Is this the bus from Gorlitz train station to Zgorzelec train station?

http://www.vgg-goerlitz.de/strecken-fahrplaene/linie/9-linie-p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes**, it is.
*Polen* is German for Poland and *Bahnhof* is German for train station, so you're looking at the Görlitz - Poland bus line.

If you click on [Fahrplan](http://www.vgg-goerlitz.de/uploads/vgg/schedule/33/download-fahrplan-linie-p.pdf) (the detailed line with stops) you get a pdf that shows **Zgorzelec Miasto**, which is the train station.

Comment: But I need the train station, not the bus station.

Comment: @kaiser updated !